# Control-C triggers logout from root in bash

Tags: linux, bash, centos, root

I'm facing a really frustrating problem on this specific server, every time I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, I logout from the root session

---

Running CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 & Bash (4.2.46-21.el7_3.x86_64)

```
[root@server ~]# uname -a  
Linux server 3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Apr 12 15:04:24 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux  
[root@server ~]# ^C   
[root@server ~]# logout
[user@server ~]$
```

Comment: That's not the default; what shell settings have been made in e.g. `.bashrc` and other init files?

Comment: What is root's login shell? `getent passwd root`

Comment: What command do you use to become root?

Answer (score 6):

[trapping-ctrl-c-in-bash](https://rimuhosting.com/knowledgebase/linux/misc/trapping-ctrl-c-in-bash) describe how to trap <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in order to trigger some action.
Please check in your `root` account (`bashrc` etc), if you are running similar trap to force *logout* when pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

> **Trapping ctrl-c in Bash**
>
> You can use the trap builtin to handle a user pressing ctrl-c during
>   the execution of a Bash script. e.g. if you need to perform some
>   cleanup functions.
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> # trap ctrl-c and call ctrl_c()
> trap ctrl_c INT
>
> function ctrl_c() {
>         echo "** Trapped CTRL-C"
> }
>
> for i in `seq 1 5`; do
>     sleep 1
>     echo -n "."
> done
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You might check if your bash environment isn't actually a wrapper around bash that just runs bash below.

We use a similiar solution on our workplace and it is used to track everything done using SSH, however the problem is exactly as yours, whenever ctrl+c is involved it likes to drop out of shell.

Answer (score 0):

In every OS you can find Signals which should be handled . There is three reactions to signals : 1 - ignore it , 2 - handle it by yourself , 3- leave it to OS . Ctrl + C is hangup signal by default . you use `trap` command to handle signal . also check ASCII standard on your system , some coding maybe different. check `man ascii` for HUP sign and its belongs charterer.
trap command example:
`trap "echo hi" SIGINT` which print hi every time you press Ctrl + C . Also you can find list of signal by the command of `kill -l` .